# Can't find rbenv after puppet install

Tags: puppet, rbenv

I am using puppet to setup a ruby on rails server (14.04). The install seems to work fine but then I can't find rbenv or bundler and ruby -v reports the system ruby 1.9.3.

Install plugin module

```
puppet module install jdowning-rbenv
```

pp file

```
class rails-test_server {
include ruby
class { rbenv: }
  rbenv::plugin { 'sstephenson/ruby-build': }
  rbenv::build { '2.2.0': global => true }
}
```

in the module

```
[$install_dir]
#   This is where rbenv will be installed to.
#   Default: '/usr/local/rbenv'
#
# [$owner]
#   This defines who owns the rbenv install directory.
#   Default: 'root'
```

Here is the output

```
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for rails-test
Info: Applying configuration version '1424804476'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rbenv::Deps::Debian/Package[build-essential]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rbenv::Deps::Debian/Package[libssl-dev]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rbenv::Deps::Debian/Package[libffi-dev]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rbenv::Deps::Debian/Package[libreadline6-dev]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Git/Package[git]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'present'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rbenv/Exec[git-clone-rbenv]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rbenv/File[/usr/local/rbenv]/group: group changed 'root' to 'adm'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rbenv/File[/usr/local/rbenv]/mode: mode changed '0755' to '0775'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rbenv/File[/usr/local/rbenv/shims]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rbenv/File[/usr/local/rbenv/plugins]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rbenv/File[/usr/local/rbenv/versions]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rails-test_server/Rbenv::Plugin[sstephenson/ruby-build]/Exec[install-sstephenson/ruby-build]/returns: executed successfully
Info: /Stage[main]/Rails-test_server/Rbenv::Plugin[sstephenson/ruby-build]/Exec[install-sstephenson/ruby-build]: Scheduling refresh of Exec[rbenv-permissions-sstephenson/ruby-build]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rails-test_server/Rbenv::Plugin[sstephenson/ruby-build]/Exec[rbenv-permissions-sstephenson/ruby-build]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rbenv/File[/etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}1895fedb6a7fdc5feed9b2cbbb8bbb60'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rails-test_server/Rbenv::Build[2.2.0]/Exec[own-plugins-2.2.0]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rails-test_server/Rbenv::Build[2.2.0]/Exec[git-pull-rubybuild-2.2.0]/returns: executed successfully            
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rails-test_server/Rbenv::Build[2.2.0]/Exec[rbenv-install-2.2.0]/returns: executed successfully
Info: /Stage[main]/Rails-test_server/Rbenv::Build[2.2.0]/Exec[rbenv-install-2.2.0]: Scheduling refresh of Exec[rbenv-ownit-2.2.0]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rails-test_server/Rbenv::Build[2.2.0]/Exec[rbenv-ownit-2.2.0]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
Info: /Stage[main]/Rails-test_server/Rbenv::Build[2.2.0]/Exec[rbenv-ownit-2.2.0]: Scheduling refresh of Exec[rbenv-global-2.2.0]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rails-test_server/Rbenv::Build[2.2.0]/Exec[rbenv-global-2.2.0]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rails-test_server/Rbenv::Build[2.2.0]/Rbenv::Gem[bundler-2.2.0]/Exec[gem-install-bundler-2.2.0]/returns: executed successfully
Info: /Stage[main]/Rails-test_server/Rbenv::Build[2.2.0]/Rbenv::Gem[bundler-2.2.0]/Exec[gem-install-bundler-2.2.0]: Scheduling refresh of Exec[rbenv-rehash-bundler-2.2.0]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rails-test_server/Rbenv::Build[2.2.0]/Rbenv::Gem[bundler-2.2.0]/Exec[rbenv-rehash-bundler-2.2.0]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
Info: /Stage[main]/Rails-test_server/Rbenv::Build[2.2.0]/Rbenv::Gem[bundler-2.2.0]/Exec[rbenv-rehash-bundler-2.2.0]: Scheduling refresh of Exec[rbenv-permissions-bundler-2.2.0]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rails-test_server/Rbenv::Build[2.2.0]/Rbenv::Gem[bundler-2.2.0]/Exec[rbenv-permissions-bundler-2.2.0]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
Notice: Finished catalog run in 473.25 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rbenv` module creates a file `/etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh` that needs to be `sourced` before the `rbenv` will be available on the command line.

```
[root@ptierno-puppetmaster modules]# which rbenv
/usr/bin/which: no rbenv in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
[root@ptierno-puppetmaster modules]# source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh
[root@ptierno-puppetmaster modules]# which rbenv
/usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv
```

You can either `source` the file as above, or login and logout again to get a new login shell.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot EXEC $SHELL